# create new visual studio project, add files and run it - command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, command-prompt

is there any way to create a new visual studio project without using IDE, Instead use command prompt??

I am working on a project which will generate small C++ program, so i want to create a new project, add that C++ file to that project, compile and run it, all using command prompt (batch file) only..

so could anyone please let me know how to do this.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) make your project files for you. It uses a much more legible syntax, and you can also generate project files for a variety of other build systems.

As an example, here's a very basic CMake file:

```
project(Foo)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#project source files
file (GLOB HEADER_FILES "*.h" "*.hpp")
file (GLOB SOURCE_FILES "*.cpp")

# build
add_executable(Foo ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Foo ${LIBS})
```

**And here's the solution file it generates.**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "ALL_BUILD", "ALL_BUILD.vcxproj", "{66E5A2EB-A802-44A1-AC9C-906752330405}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924} = {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958} = {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "Foo", "Foo.vcxproj", "{1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958} = {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "ZERO_CHECK", "ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj", "{A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
        Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
        MinSizeRel|Win32 = MinSizeRel|Win32
        RelWithDebInfo|Win32 = RelWithDebInfo|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {66E5A2EB-A802-44A1-AC9C-906752330405}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {66E5A2EB-A802-44A1-AC9C-906752330405}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {66E5A2EB-A802-44A1-AC9C-906752330405}.MinSizeRel|Win32.ActiveCfg = MinSizeRel|Win32
        {66E5A2EB-A802-44A1-AC9C-906752330405}.RelWithDebInfo|Win32.ActiveCfg = RelWithDebInfo|Win32
        {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}.MinSizeRel|Win32.ActiveCfg = MinSizeRel|Win32
        {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}.MinSizeRel|Win32.Build.0 = MinSizeRel|Win32
        {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}.RelWithDebInfo|Win32.ActiveCfg = RelWithDebInfo|Win32
        {1A246EDB-1F39-4776-A9C0-C81AC67D1924}.RelWithDebInfo|Win32.Build.0 = RelWithDebInfo|Win32
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}.MinSizeRel|Win32.ActiveCfg = MinSizeRel|Win32
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}.MinSizeRel|Win32.Build.0 = MinSizeRel|Win32
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}.RelWithDebInfo|Win32.ActiveCfg = RelWithDebInfo|Win32
        {A0601C1A-BC0F-45D0-BDB1-C5056BD69958}.RelWithDebInfo|Win32.Build.0 = RelWithDebInfo|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityAddIns) = postSolution
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

The Project file is similarly ugly and 294 lines long.

Adding dependencies is pretty simple too, here's how you add boost:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Hey benjamin lindley, How do i run this file?? Could you please help me out, i'm not familiar with CMake!

Comment: Hey @Benjamin Lindley it says "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here"..
i have only 15.. so could u just give me a syntax how to run this file?
i created a file CMakeLists.txt with the appropriate content.. how do i run??
plz help me out..

Comment: @user737415: Oh, sorry.  I didn't realize that, it's just that the moderators are constantly hounding us to not have discussions in the comments.  Oh well.  Description follows.

Comment: Create a base directory for your project.  Then create two sub-directories.  One named "source" and one named "msvc10".

Put CMakeLists.txt inside the "source" directory along with any source files.

Navigate to the "msvc10" folder. Then type "cmake ../source".

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio projects are just XML files, so you can just study their format and write them out. (The format changed from 2008 to 2010.)
Solution files are a custom text format, but not that complicated either.

Finally, devenv.exe has a switch for "don't start the IDE, just compile this solution on the command line", which you can use to compile the resulting solution.

Comment: thanks for quick reply..! 
can you give some links regarding those formats??

Comment: Project files are more specific than XML: they're MSBuild build files, the format of which is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx). However VS supports a subset of MSBuild so one could create a file that VS cannot use but MSBuild can.